# any tool to check if servlet filter is working or not

Tags: java, firefox, servlets, firebug, servlet-filters

I have configured a servlet filter for the url pattern `/webapp/test/**`. The name of the filter is `MyTempFilter`.

Can we check if the request containing the pattern `/webapp/test/**` is intercepted by MyTempFilter.

Is there any tool or extension to Mozilla.

I have firebug in my Mozilla.

Comment: Debugging Filter by putting break point in it in your IDE. Or more simpler put a `System.out.print("I'm in Filter");` inside it and run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @harry said in development mode putting breakpoints in the `filter` is the best way

And I found one more use full extensions for browser here

As it returns the debug summery  to the browser as commented `HTML`, so it can be be seen via “View Source” browser command.

[Http Servlet Debug Filter](http://www.brsanthu.com/blog/2008/10/http-servlet-debug-filter/)

Comment: cheers :)don't forget to up vote and mark answer if its useful.